# Implement time based notifications in Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created an events app using Firebase as database , which contains all the events occurring in my college , every event in database has a date child with it.

I'm unable to figure out how can I send notifications to every user about the event occurring on that date (for ex: suppose there is an event about vr on 12th April then i want users to receive notification on that day  saying that you have so and so event in your college today )

I know there is FCM, but I don't want to manually send notifications everyday to hundreds of users.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out here.

Comment: I recomand you to use `onesignal.com`. You can send notifications programmatically from your for free.

Comment: Check out the new firebase functions https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Answer (score 1):

You have some options for scheduling a function to run periodically.  [This sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron) goes over some options for creating an HTTPS endpoint that's pinged periodically by another service that you configure.

You can also schedule functions via pubsub as described in [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html).

Please also file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for things you would like to see supported directly.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud functions will not work for you without a server, since all the listeners they have are based in database, sign up or authentication events.

The solution is to add to your app [Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) support and create a server in [Java](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) or in [Node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages) that from X minutes to X minutes checks the list of events and send a notification to the users that are subscribing them.